# Geofence triggering procedure explanation needed?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-geofence, location-client

SO I've created geofence as below:

```
    GeofenceModel modelExit = new GeofenceModel.Builder("id_oi_456")
                .setTransition(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)
                .setExpiration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setLatitude(40.414341)
                .setLongitude(49.928548)
                .setRadius(CLIENT_GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
                .build();


    SmartLocation.with(this).geofencing()
                .add(modelExit)
                .start(this);
```

I run this code once, it triggers when dwelling inside geofence (as expected). And then I delete the snippet and rerun the project. But geofence not triggered this time even if I have set NEVER_EXPIRE. So basically what I want to know is that where are the geonfences stored. In case they are stored outside app memory then why "deleting snippet" clears geofence?

Comment: Please see my [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50869301/766755) as I think it will help elaborate on all of the cases you need to handle to re-register geofences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is working as intended. The project that goes to re-run will consider the app as fresh install. As stated in the documentation - [Use Best Practices for Geofencing](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#BestPractices):

> The app must re-register geofences if they're still needed after the following events, since the system cannot recover the geofences in the following cases:
>
> - The device is rebooted. The app should listen for the device's boot complete action, and then re- register the geofences required.
> - The app is uninstalled and re-installed.
> - The app's data is cleared.
> - Google Play services data is cleared.
> - The app has received a GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE alert. This typically happens after NLP (Android's Network Location Provider) is disabled.

Hope this helps.